# Relationship Between Derivatives and Conditional Probabilities

Tags: calculus, probability, limits, statistics, derivatives

I was reading [this link](https://data.princeton.edu/wws509/notes/c7s1) on "Survival Models" used in modelling econometrics and biological related data. In particular, consider the **Hazard Function** (denoted by $\lambda$):<sup>[src)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4a19T.png)</sup>

$$ \lambda(t) = \lim_{dt \to 0} \frac{\operatorname{Pr}\{ t \leq T < t + dt \mid T \geq t\}}{dt} $$

The Hazard Function is used to characterize the probability of some "event" happening at an instantaneous time point of $t$. From a probabilistic interpretation, the Hazard Function is defined as the conditional probability of a random variable $T$ taking a value between a small range $t$ and $t+dt$, conditional on the this random variable $T$ already being larger than some value $t$ – we then take the derivative of this conditional probability.

This is where my confusion begins:

- If we define $f(t)$ to be the probability distribution function of the random variable $T$
- If we define $F(t)$ to be the cumulative probability distribution of the random variable $T$
- If we define $S(t)$ to be $1 - F(t)$
- Then: $\lambda(t) = f(t)/S(t)$

We are often told that this relationship ($\lambda(t) = f(t)/S(t)$) is simply "by definition" – but I am curious in knowing if using the laws of calculus and probability, we can somehow understand the justification as to why $\lambda(t)$ can be defined as $\lambda(t) = f(t)/S(t)$.

- Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Thank you!

Note: Apparently, $\lambda(t)$ also equals $\lambda(t) = - S'(t)/S(t)$.

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your question. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Also, the indicated relation can be derived from the limit definition by noting that $$ \operatorname{Pr}\{ t \leq T < t + dt \mid T \geq t\} = \frac{\operatorname{Pr}\{ t \leq T < t + dt\}}{\operatorname{Pr}\{T \geq t\}} = \frac{1}{S(t)} \int_{t}^{t+dt} f(s) \, \mathrm{d}s. $$

Comment: @ Sangchul Lee: thank you so much for your suggestions and your comments!